# Trouble Receiving Inputs in WSO2 API Manager Endpoint with Java and Spring Boot Setup

Tags: java, spring-boot, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I recently found the need for WSO2 API Manager. I require it for the initial setup to create an API for token retrieval. However, when I define the endpoint and deploy it, the software is unable to receive inputs.

If my explanation is unclear, I apologize. Below, I am providing you with some documentation to clarify the issue.

It's worth mentioning that the endpoint is designed in Java and uses the Spring Boot framework.

Here is endpoint response ( which method is post ):
[endpoint response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDNCm.png)

Resource Definition :
[Resource parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACmgQ.png)

I expect the parameters of the requests to be sent to the endpoint through API!

Comment: If you can post the expected request body and path in the backend, I can help with creating the API.

Comment: @Pubci Thanks for your cooperation. i need to send like this through wso2: curl --location 'https://example.com/token/getToken' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  --data '{
    "username" : "hamid",
    "password" : "1111"
}'

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API with a resource as /getToken.

[image: API Resource]

And then you can define the backend endpoint as http://example.com/token.

[image: API backend endpoint]

The idea here is that the resource gets appended to the backend request. So if you have a resource called /foo and if you define the backend endpoint as http://alpha.com/bar. Then the backend will receive a call as http://alpha.com/bar/foo.

Comment: Thank you; yes, I followed the same process you mentioned. However, the issue lies elsewhere. In Postman, to handle this type of data, it should be sent through the body, considering its type as raw.
Moreover, when sending a curl request, we should use the long form to achieve the desired result. Unfortunately, I couldn't find these settings in WSO2.

Comment: For token based API access requirement, create and configure an API as shown by @Pubci and use the Security (Toggle Enabled) and this would have a flow as- 1. Generate the token via WSO2 default token API  
2. Use the token in header (Authorization  Bearer <TOKEN>) to call the real backend service

Comment: I appreciate your support. This API doesn't require a token; it handles token creation internally. The issue at hand is that the input parameters are not being sent to it in the correct format. As I mentioned, my investigations revealed that the problem lies in the format of the curl sent by WSO2.

Comment: Then you should go with APIKey based approach to have some sort of API GW security. Also, please use gateway URL for the api and pass the body with respective headers (Content-Type) and it should work then.